# how can i perform action after action in python?

Tags: python, notifications, action, schedule, alarm

how can my code python code perform predetermined actions, after specified times? with the time in-between the actions being non-uniform? the current code displayed loops but i want the first action to initiate then stop for the next action to initiate when its time. i am building an automated notification system that is supposed to send an alarm after different non uniform times. The current code does not bring any output and when it does, it keeps looping.

```
#import win_sound

import time

import datetime

from datetime import date

import calendar

my_date = date.today()
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
x = dt.strftime("%H:%M")

#first function
def assembly():
    print("morning")

#second function
def mental_math():
    print("afternoon")

#loop to ensure code is always checking for time
while True:
    #checks if today's date and time matches with specified date and time
    Today = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]
    if Today == 'Friday':
        if x == "10:18":
            assembly()
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            pass

        
    if Today == 'Friday':
        if x == "10:17":
            mental_math()
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            pass
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) or [`cron`](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron/)

Comment: thank you that worked. i used schedule